# WPF TextBlock Style Underline on Mouse Hover

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

Simple question. Can the following WPF C# code cut down some weight? I mean, WTF, uh... I mean WPF, come one. Have you every seen CSS? I only want to underline the Text when I hover with the mouse just like a link. Do I really have to add 9 lines for that?

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Cassette_tblPrintLabel" Text="Print Label" Canvas.Left="154" Canvas.Top="215" Foreground="#FF3355FF" Cursor="Hand" MouseDown="Cassette_lblPrintLabel_MouseDown">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecoration" Value="Underline" />
            </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean to write `TextBlock.TextDecoration` or was it supposed to be `TextBlock.TextDecorations`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add the style as resource; then at least you can re-use it.  I think that's the best you can do.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="HoverUnderlineStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>

<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HoverUnderlineStyle}" />
```

Comment: This keeps the code cleaner indeed. As there might not be an alternative I will accept this as the answer.

Comment: TextDecoration must be TextDecorations, otherwise the compiler complains

Comment: I wonder how this could be done with an attached property or a behavior. Attached property is most concise and easiest to combine I think.